# Centos: Failed to start LSB: Start the NuoDB Admin

Tags: nuodb

I've installed NuoDB on Centos 8 and I'm trying to start nuoadmin using this command in cmd:

> `sudo service nuoadmin start`

but it throws error:

> Starting nuoadmin (via systemctl):  Job for nuoadmin.service failed
>   because the control process exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl
>   status nuoadmin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When i type command: `systemctl status nuoadmin.service`, it shows this problem:

```
nuoadmin.service - LSB: Start the NuoDB Admin
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/nuoadmin; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-01-19 18:34:24 MSK; 26min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16303 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/nuoadmin start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start the NuoDB Admin...
Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain nuoadmin[16303]: /etc/rc.d/init.d/nuoadmin: line 98: su: command not found
Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain nuoadmin[16303]: /etc/rc.d/init.d/nuoadmin: line 186: su: command not found
Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain nuoadmin[16303]: Starting NuoDB Admin[FAILED]
Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nuoadmin.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nuoadmin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 19 18:34:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start the NuoDB Admin.
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Note that NuoDB hasn't yet been released with support for RedHat 8 / CentOS 8.  However, it looks to me like you need to install the package containing the `su` command.  I don't have access to a CentOS 8 system so I can't tell you which package contains it.  In previous versions of RedHat/CentOS, I believe it was part of the `coreutils` package.